# How to call Service with dynamic intervals

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

Hi in my application i am execute webview with dynamic intervals by using Background Service and Alarm manager.Webview will open with specified time interval.If after starting service user can change interval time (that is different for first time interval) here i want to update this time interval into alarm manager.

Here,what i am trying

```
private void loadWebview() {
    try {
        loadPrefValues();

        Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, XorWebView.class);
        webViewIntent.putExtra("url", mStr);
        webViewIntent.putExtra("duration", mDurationStr);
        webViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyService.this, 0,
                webViewIntent, 0);

        alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("1 minute")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("2 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("5 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("10 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("30 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("60 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("Service.onStart()" + "Url:" + mStr
            + "Send to WebActivity");
}
```

This method will execute only first time specified interval.What wrong in my code?

Edit # 1

In MainActivity i am using on/off switch button and listview for intervals.In list view i put 1,5,10,20,30,60 minutes.user can select any intervals in list view and when switch isChecked() i start a service here.

In this service class i call intervals by using Alarmmanager.

what i want exact when user change interval in main activity that interval will updated in alarm manager.

My service class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;
String mStr, mIntervalStr, mDurationStr;
PendingIntent pintent;
AlarmManager alarm;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    System.out.println("Service.onCreate()");

}

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
    try {
        loadWebview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service command started",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}


private void loadWebview() {
    try {
        loadPrefValues();

        Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, XorWebView.class);
        webViewIntent.putExtra("url", mStr);
        webViewIntent.putExtra("duration", mDurationStr);
        webViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyService.this, 0,
                webViewIntent, 0);

        alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("1 minute")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    1 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("2 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("5 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("10 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("30 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("60 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("Service.onStart()" + "Url:" + mStr
            + "Send to WebActivity");
}

private void loadPrefValues() {
    SharedPrefManager.Init(MyService.this);
    SharedPrefManager.LoadFromPref();
    String s1 = SharedPrefManager.getsUrl().toString();
    String s2 = SharedPrefManager.getsInterval().toString();
    String s3 = SharedPrefManager.getsDuration().toString();

    mStr = s1;
    mIntervalStr = s2;
    mDurationStr = s3;


}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mReceiver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    alarm.cancel(pintent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("Service.onDestroy()");
}
```

}

Comment: Copy and paste your AlarmManager code(from loadWebView() function) in your activity, When you can update your alarmManager from your activity then why you want to update it from your service class????

Comment: Update your interval from your activity, No need to change it from service.

Comment: Because,I want to run this service in background(if my app will close (or) Reboot i want to run this service).So,that's why i want to update it into service class.How can i update it in main activity pls send me solution.

Comment: Look, You will update it when user will select value from listview; Its mean, AlarmManager will only updated when your application is visible. AlarmManager will keep working even if app is closed, don't worry about it.

Comment: It will run every interval without opening app after rebooting

Comment: You can implement Broadcast listener for rebooting. and can start alarmManager on Reboot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116877/cant-complete-after-boot-listener-in-android/7116902#7116902

Comment: and even if you set alarmManager in your service, then you have to implement this reboot listener to start service of reboot. Because services also killed on rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

You should cancel previous pendingIntent first then set new.

In your code after this line.

```
alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

put

```
alarm.cancel(pintent);
```

Comment: yes i added the above line But,that alarm will triggered with first time selecting interval.

Comment: Exactly what i wont : when second time alarm manager calls i want to execute loadwebview() before alarm.setRepeting() execution.How can i call loadWebview()..

Comment: where are you listening alarm broadcast???? You can invoke your methods like loadWebview() from broadcast listener!                     Your requirements are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Following things are happening.

->Update alarmManager from your activity.
->Save current Time interval in preferences for future use.
->Implement reboot broadcast receiver, When device rebooted it will called.
->Set alarmManager in reboot function. Use time interval which is saved in preferences.

Copy this code into your activity.

```
       listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
                        loadWebView(user's new selected minutes);
                    }
});
```

Here is code to set AlarmManager

```
     private void loadWebview(String minutes) {
    try {
        loadPrefValues();



        saveCurrentTimeInterval(minutes);




        Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, XorWebView.class);
        webViewIntent.putExtra("url", mStr);
        webViewIntent.putExtra("duration", mDurationStr);
        webViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyService.this, 0,
                webViewIntent, 0);

        alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (minutes.equals("1 minute")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (minutes.equals("2 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("5 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("10 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("30 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
        if (mIntervalStr.equals("60 minutes")) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

private void saveCurrentTimeInterval(String minute)
{
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
eidtor.putString("interval", minute);
editor.commit();
}

Now ReBoot listener

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;    

public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        setAlarmManager(pref.getString("interval", ""));   

    }  

    private void setAlarmManager(String minutes) {
        try {
            loadPrefValues();

            Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, XorWebView.class);
            webViewIntent.putExtra("url", mStr);
            webViewIntent.putExtra("duration", mDurationStr);
            webViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyService.this, 0,
                    webViewIntent, 0);

            alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (minutes.equals("1 minute")) {
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
            }
            if (minutes.equals("2 minutes")) {
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
            }
            if (mIntervalStr.equals("5 minutes")) {
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
            }
            if (mIntervalStr.equals("10 minutes")) {
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
            }
            if (mIntervalStr.equals("30 minutes")) {
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
            }
            if (mIntervalStr.equals("60 minutes")) {
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 60 * 1000, pintent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

In you xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">  
            <intent-filter>     
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Also add this permission in your manifest.                                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: i am tried above code it will call service but,Alarm is not working after rebooting.